# Node.js | Trigger a function in PUG template when ioHook is activated by key hook?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a simple node.js app with a javascript file and a pug template file.
In the javascript file I required iohook and the code logic itself works. It detects pressed keys and I can do actions based on that.

But here is my problem: I have a pug-template for my layout with a few simple buttons and divs. If you click the button, the div starts a timer - imagine: 60 seconds timer starts onClick. This also works.

Now I want to combine these two: If I press a certain key like "1" it should start the timer for the first div. But here is my problem: I failed to combine these two.

Now my question is what are you recommendations to solve this? I don't really know how to continue. Any tips are appreciated!

I tried to require iohook inside the PUG template but that doesn't work because the scope of the template doesn't know the require function.

If i try to pass ioHook to the template, it always throws the error, that it is undefined.

index.js

```
const ioHook = require('iohook');

ioHook.on('keydown', event => {
    if ( event['keycode'] == 55 ) {
 // do something
});

ioHook.start(true);
```

index.pug

```
html
  body
    .button
      .top-div(onclick="startTimer(60, document.querySelector('#top-span'));")
        | TOP
        span#top-span


script.



    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        let timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        let IntervalId = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        display.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        display.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "grey";

        if (timer > 0)
    {
        --timer;
    }
    else
    {
        display.style.backgroundColor = "limegreen";
        display.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "limegreen";
        clearInterval(IntervalId);
    }

    }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using iohook? That's for NodeJS (or rather the server on which NodeJS will be runnning). If you wanna handle keypress events in the Browser (i.e. the client) you should just use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Or are you trying to trigger cleint-side Javascript function from server-side NodeJS?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to trigger my "startTimer" function when I press a key - for example "1". Even if the nodejs app is not active, it should get triggered. Thats why I used iohook. And the code itself works (the hook) but i don't know how to trigger the function now. Maybe with an event that gets routed to the template file but I don't exactly know how to do that.